# How to reference the global variables within another function in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops

Send a answer to me...[And tell me how to fluency in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OfWm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If my intuition is right, what you are trying to do is to take the values of the list into a function that you have just defined. If it's the case, use this:

```
l1 = [10,20,30,40,50]
l2 = [10,30,40,50,10]

def fun_1(list1):
    if(list1[0] == list1[4]):
        print("both are same")
    else:
        print("both are not same")

def fun_2(list2):
    if(list2[0] == list2[4]):
        print("both are same")
    else:
        print("both are not same")
    
fun_1(l1)
fun_2(l2)
```